# typescript set params signature to match another functions params signature

Tags: typescript

I want to do something along the lines of

```js
addEventListener(...args: Parameters<EventEmitter>) {
    this.on(args);
  }
```

But it's really working.

first error for `...args: Parameters<EventEmitter>` is `Rest parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.`

the second error for  `this.on(args)` is `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.`

I know that `this.on` is an `EventEmitter` and I basically want to rename it so I can do `this.addEventListener` on my instance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a bit more? What's the constraint?

Comment: @Wolfgang I updated the question with the error messages. Was that what you meant by constraints?

Comment: It says `Type 'EventEmitter<string... does not satisfy the constraint` that's the part that I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```js
  addEventListener(...args: Parameters<EventEmitter['on']>) {
    this.on(...args);
  }
```

(was really close to the solution)